# Tableau Public, error message {"error":{"message":"No author found!"}}

Tags: tableau-api

I published something onto Tableau Public and it isn't working for some reason.  This just started happening and I am not sure why.  I tried uploading different workbooks none of them are working.  Here is a sample:

https://public.tableausoftware.com/views/JBCBacktestvs_SP500/JBC-Backtestvs_SP500DB?:embed=y&:display_count=no

This is the error I receive when I log onto it:

```
 {"error":{"message":"No author found!"}}
```

Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?  Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to log on to Tableau Public? Did any errors occur when you published the workbook?

Comment: I am able to log on Tableau Public and I did not have any errors.  Thank you

Comment: https://public.tableausoftware.com/profile/yan.wu4001#!/vizhome/JBC-Backtestvs_SP500/JBC-Backtestvs_SP500DB  This is the link that I got to work.  However, this is not the link generated.

Comment: When you say "generated", when and where was that original link generated?

Comment: You already have a link that works.  Is there a reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: My apologies for not being clear.  This link was generated from when I published the workbook and doesn't work https://public.tableausoftware.com/views/JBCBacktestvs_SP500/JBC-Backtestvs_SP500DB?:embed=y&:display_count=no  This is the link i manually created from being familiar with tableau: https://public.tableausoftware.com/profile/yan.wu4001#!/vizhome/JBC-Backtestvs_SP500/JBC-Backtestvs_SP500DB

Comment: In Tableau Public, try the File > Manage workbooks option.  After you sign on and get to the Tableau Public web page, do you see your workbooks?

Comment: I'm getting the same error.

The issue isn't the ability to see the workbook from within public.tableausoftware.com once one signs in. The issue is the ability for non-signed in person to be able to see one's workbook.

The URL in question is the provided by Tableau after the workbook is saved: "Copy and Paste link into your email message"

Comment: Try posting your question on the Tableau forum (http://community.tableausoftware.com/community/forums).  There's a more active group of Tableau users there.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the methods given in the tableau help section. After the account is made a window with all the story board will come up. Select the story or dashboard (as per the case) and then click on share button . 
click on Done and then go to "open in browser window" . It will open in the browser. Copy the address in the address bar of the browser. This is the link to be published